# Plaid with Stripe Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, plaid

I have an application successfully using Stripe to charge users for access to an application.  Building on to this, I would like to implement Plaid in my checkout process.  Since this was my first time implementing Stripe, and now my first time with Plaid, I am a bit lost regarding the directions and how to push this feature forward.

I installed the [plaid-ruby gem](https://github.com/plaid/plaid-ruby), and added my Plaid secret_key and client_id via figaro but now I am lost.

**Plaid.rb:**

```
   Plaid.configuration.stripe = {
    p.client_id = ENV['PLAID_CLIENT_ID'],
    p.secret = ENV['PLAID_SECRET_KEY'],
    p.env = :tartan  # or :production
  end
```

**The Plaid Link:**

```
       <button id='linkButton'>Open Plaid Link</button>
        <script src="https://cdn.plaid.com/link/stable/link-initialize.js"></script>
        <script>
        var linkHandler = Plaid.create({
          env: 'tartan',
          clientName: 'ACCR',
          key: '<<< MY_PUBLIC_KEY >>>',
          product: 'auth',
          selectAccount: true,
          env: 'tartan',
          onSuccess: function(public_token, metadata) {
            // Send the public_token and account ID to your app server.
            console.log('public_token: ' + public_token);
            console.log('account ID: ' + metadata.account_id);
          },
        });

        // Trigger the Link UI
        document.getElementById('linkButton').onclick = function() {
          linkHandler.open();
        };
        </script>
```

Here's what I have in my controller for Stripe:

```
    def new 
    @stripe_btn_data = {
     key: "#{ Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] }",
    }   
    end

  #1 Create a charge
      customer = if current_user.stripe_id?
                    Stripe::Customer.retrieve(current_user.stripe_id)
                  else
                    Stripe::Customer.create(email: :stripeEmail)
                  end

      current_user.update(
        stripe_id: customer.id,
      )

       stripe_charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
         customer:    customer.id,
         amount:      (current_order.subtotal * 100).to_i,
         currency:    'usd',
       )
... more information to create an order then send email after charge.
```

What do I need to include in my controller, or elsewhere, to create a charge via Plaid and Stripe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plaid has a [writeup](https://plaid.com/docs/link/stripe) on how to wire this up - though the provided example is in Node.js - and Stripe has a [guide](https://stripe.com/docs/ach) too.

That said, you'll need to add code in the `onSuccess` handler to send the `public_token` and `metadata.account_id` to your server's ['token exchange' endpoint](https://plaid.com/docs/link/stripe/#step-4-write-server-side-handler) and once you've got that, you can exchange those for [the Stripe token](https://github.com/plaid/plaid-ruby#exchanging-a-link-public-token-for-a-plaid-access-token), and finally, you'll need to attach that token to the Customer.

So, something like this:

```
plaid_user = Plaid::User.exchange_token(
  public_token,
  metadata_dot_account_id,
  product: :auth
)

puts plaid_user.stripe_bank_account_token

customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve("<customer-id>")

customer.sources.create({
  :source => plaid_user.stripe_bank_account_token
})
```

And then you can do your `Stripe::Charge.create()`.

Comment: I see the public_token and account_id in the console. How would I send this information to the plaid-ruby gem ( 'token exchange' endpoint)?  Do I do this through the plaid_user = Plaid... or does that go in my controller?

Comment: I was able to get this to work by passing the curl into the controller then passing the customer = .. as you have above.  Thank you!

Comment: Awesome.  Glad to hear it. :)

Comment: I'm returning a no such token error, any chance anyone might know where this is coming from?

Comment: Check to make sure the public and secret API keys are both from the same account and from the same environment.